# SSRS Exception after migration

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have migrated SQL Server 2008 R2 based SSRS to SQL Server 2016 SSRS. I am getting the following error every 10 minutes in the logs. Schedules are not updating Next Run time after Job execution.

> library!WindowsService_3!28c4!01/31/2020-00:02:08:: i INFO: Call to CleanBatch()
>   library!WindowsService_3!28c4!01/31/2020-00:02:08:: e ERROR: Throwing Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ReportServerStorageException: , An error occurred within the report server database.  This may be due to a connection failure, timeout or low disk condition within the database.;
>   dbcleanup!WindowsService_3!28c4!01/31/2020-00:02:08:: e ERROR: Error in CleanExpiredContentCache: Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ReportServerStorageException: An error occurred within the report server database.  This may be due to a connection failure, timeout or low disk condition within the database.
>
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid object name 'ReportServerTempDB.dbo.ContentCache'.
>   runningjobs!WindowsService_3!28c4!01/31/2020-00:02:08:: e ERROR: Error in timer Database Cleanup (NT Service) : Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ReportServerStorageException: An error occurred within the report server database.  This may be due to a connection failure, timeout or low disk condition within the database. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid object name 'ReportServerTempDB.dbo.ContentCache'.

Comment: It seems your report server db and report server tempdb is not upgraded to 2016. Report server couldn't find the table ReportServerTempDB.dbo.ContentCache.

Comment: After installation of SSRS we have restored database from sql 2008 R2 backup. May be that could be the reason ? Also Schedules are expiring after each execution. If i open schedule and just click apply without changing anything then it updates Next run time.

Comment: Yes, that sounds the reason. You can try to change the reporting db using SSRS configuration tool.